# date time with document.getElementById not working

Tags: javascript, datetime, forms

beneath you see a piece of custom code for Zendesk. Everything works fine, till I want to implement a date/time snippet.

**Normally the script works like this:**

1 - there is a button which says "Print Ticket".

2 - The button has a onclick event to open a printer friendly page ready for printing.

After implementing the date/time code (what I didn't do well I believe) I only get the printable version of the ticket, but the time isn't displayed. (nothing happended really)

The only thing what happends is that the date and time are shown without the rest of the printable form.

I think the placemanet of the javascript is not in th right place, it needs to be in the head section which is generated also by javascript

Can anyone please help me with this? or point me in a vorm of example what to do?

```
<style>
input.createtable {
    display:none;
}
</style>
<script language="JavaScript">

// Get today's current date.
var now = new Date();

// Array list of days.
var days = new Array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');

// Array list of months.
var months = new Array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');

// Calculate the number of the current day in the week.
var date = ((now.getDate()<10) ? "0" : "")+ now.getDate();

// Calculate four digit year.
function fourdigits(number) {
    return (number < 1000) ? number + 1900 : number;
                                }

// Join it all together
today =  days[now.getDay()] + ", " +
         months[now.getMonth()] + " " +
         date + ", " +
         (fourdigits(now.getYear())) ;

// Print out the data.
// document.write(today);

// Begin altered code

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = today;

// End altered code

//  End -->
</script>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
writeConsole = function(content) {
 top.consoleRef=window.open('','myconsole',
  'width=800,height=800'
   +',menubar=0'
   +',toolbar=0'
   +',status=0'
   +',scrollbars=1'
   +',resizable=1')
// top.consoleRef.document.open("text/html","replace");
 top.consoleRef.document.writeln(
  '<html><head><title>Signature Page</title></head>'
 +'<style>th {color: #FFFFFF;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;background-color:#CCCCCC;}tr {color: #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;}td.small {color: #000000; font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}td.large {color: #000000; font-size: 120%; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: bold; text-align:center;}</style>'
 +'<link href="http://asset3.zendesk.com/stylesheets_old/zd_print.css?1270161524" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'
 +'<body onLoad="self.focus()" style="background: white; font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">'
 +'<center><A HREF="javascript:window.print()">Print Werkorder</A></center>'
 +'<table width="100%"><tr><td align="left" valign="middle">'
 +'</td><br />'
 +'www.domain.nl<br />'
 +'Tel: 058-111111111<br />'
 +'E-mail info@domain.nl'
 +'</tr></table>'
 +content
 +'</body></html>'
 )
 top.consoleRef.document.close()
}
//-->
</script>


<form>
  <input class="createtable" name=userInput type=textarea size="1" value="<table width=100% height=825 border=0 cellpadding=6 cellspacing=4>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=6><h1>WERKORDER NR#: {{ticket.id}}</h1></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=6><hr width=100% noshade=noshade /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width=13% valign=top><strong>Klantinformatie:</strong></td>
    <td width=87% align=left valign=top><p><strong>Datum:    <div id=date></div>  

    <br />
      Naam</strong>: {{ticket.requester.name}}<br />
      <strong>Bedrijf:</strong> {{ticket.organization.name}}<br />
      <strong>Telefoonnummer:</strong> {{ticket.ticket_field_484140}}<br />
    <strong>E-mail:</strong> {{ticket.requester.email}}</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign=top><strong>In ontvangst genomen:</strong></td>
    <td align=left valign=top><strong>Merk &amp; Model:</strong> {{ticket.ticket_field_483591}}<br />
      <strong>Hardware Type:</strong> {{ticket.ticket_field_484179}}<br />
      <strong>Uitbesteed:</strong> {{ticket.ticket_field_483608}}<br />
    <strong>Prioriteit:</strong> {{ticket.priority}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=6><hr width=100% noshade=noshade /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign=top><strong>Overeengekomen:</strong></td>
    <td colspan=5 rowspan=2 valign=top><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=6><hr width=100% noshade=noshade /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign=top><strong>Handtekening voor akkoord:</strong></td>
    <td colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=7 cellpadding=7>
      <tr>
        <td width=33%>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width=33%>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width=31%>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width=33%><hr noshade=noshade /></td>
        <td width=33%><hr /></td>
        <td><hr /></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width=33%> {{ticket.requester.name}} </td>
        <td width=33%>Datum:</td>
        <td>Plaats:</td>
        </tr>
      </table>      <p><br />
    </p></td>
  </tr>
</table>">
  <input type=button value="Print Werkorder"
onClick="writeConsole(this.form.userInput.value)"
>
</form>
```

**Edit question**

This is what I have now, the form appears again, but without a date, why is this?

I'll post in short the code again:

**the altered javascript:**

```
<script language="JavaScript">

// Get today's current date.
var now = new Date();

// Array list of days.
var days = new Array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');

// Array list of months.
var months = new Array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');

// Calculate the number of the current day in the week.
var date = ((now.getDate()<10) ? "0" : "")+ now.getDate();

// Calculate four digit year.
function fourdigits(number) {
    return (number < 1000) ? number + 1900 : number;
                                }

// Join it all together
today =  days[now.getDay()] + ", " +
         months[now.getMonth()] + " " +
         date + ", " +
         (fourdigits(now.getYear())) ;

// Print out the data.
// document.write(today);

// Begin altered code

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = today;

// End altered code

//  End -->
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know if it's just a formatting thing with Stack Overflow, but you don't seem to have any quotes around your HTML attributes.

Comment: I think it's needed to let it all work, it's a sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi
Just add following line
**top.consoleRef.document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = today;**

before
 **top.consoleRef.document.close()**

and comment the following line.

**//document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = today;**

This is because your date element is as a value of textbox and it is not a part of DOM.
So after writing it on document, you can access it through DOM.

Comment: thanks a ton, 1 line from you and and 3 days/evenings of google finally paid off :D