# Replace document.write with document.getelementbyid

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add current date/time to a site.  I found clues here: [date time with document.getElementById not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105369/date-time-with-document-getelementbyid-not-working) with the code I'm using referenced, but I'm looking for a different output.  Please see the following code below.  Basically, I'm trying to push the output to a span for display on the page.  What I have now is not working. Thanks in advance for any help provided.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Date Time Script</title>
</head>
<body>

<span id="spanDate"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">


// Get today's current date.
var now = new Date();

// Array list of days.
var days = new Array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');

// Array list of months.
var months = new Array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');

// Calculate the number of the current day in the week.
var date = ((now.getDate()<10) ? "0" : "")+ now.getDate();

// Calculate four digit year.
function fourdigits(number) {
return (number < 1000) ? number + 1900 : number;
                            }
// Altered code
// Join it all together
document.getElementByID("spanDate").innerHTML = days[now.getDay()] + ", " +
     months[now.getMonth()] + " " +
     date + ", " +
     (fourdigits(now.getYear())) ;

//Original code
// Print out the data.
//document.write(today);

//  End -->
</script>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementByID` <-- it's Id not ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a typo:

```
document.getElementByID("spanDate")...
```

should be:

```
document.getElementById("spanDate")
```

here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HWA4X/

Comment: Thanks!! I missed something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `days[date%7]` instead of `days[now.getDay()]`.